# Want to combine redundant Methods of pulling user/patient images into one method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-file

I have a nine of ImageViews set in the xml layout. My application pulls images directly from a folder on the device and loads the image onto those ImageViews. Because of the redundancy my applications is slowing down the more patients/users that I add. I'm sure there is way to combine these methods (doing the exact same thing) into one method, Im just not sure how, I'm thinking of creating a file array. Any ideas?

[image]

This is my code regarding the nine ImageViews being declared and instantiated

```
ImageView patientOne;
ImageView patientTwo;
ImageView patientThree; 
ImageView patientFour; 
ImageView patientFive; 
ImageView patientSix; 
ImageView patientSeven; 
ImageView patientEight; 
ImageView patientNine;

public void initializeViews() {
    patientOne=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_one);
    patientTwo=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_two);
    patientThree=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_three);
    patientFour=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_four);
    patientFive=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_five);
    patientSix=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_six);
    patientSeven=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_seven);
    patientEight=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_eight);
    patientNine=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_nine);
    newPatient = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_patient);
}
```

These are my nine redundant commands pulling the patient's/user's images from the specific corresponding directories

```
public void getPatientOne() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PerinatalMonitor/Patient1/patient.jpg";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        patientOne.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }
}

public void getPatientTwo() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PerinatalMonitor/Patient2/patient.jpg";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        patientTwo.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }   
}

public void getPatientThree() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PerinatalMonitor/Patient3/patient.jpg";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        patientThree.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }
}

public void getPatientFour() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PerinatalMonitor/Patient4/patient.jpg";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        patientFour.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }
}

public void getPatientFive() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PerinatalMonitor/Patient5/patient.jpg";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        patientFive.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }
}

public void getPatientSix() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PerinatalMonitor/Patient6/patient.jpg";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        patientSix.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }
}
//And so on and so forth until I have nine Patients
}//end of class
```

These are the methods called in my onCreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);

    initializeViews(); 

    getPatientOne();
    getPatientTwo();
    getPatientThree();
    getPatientFour();
    getPatientFive();
    getPatientSix();
}
```

In case you are currious, this is how I am  creating the patient folders

```
//  Name of Folder = Patient's Number + randomInt
public void createPatientFolder() {

    count=count+1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("/PerinatalMonitor/Patient");
    sb.append(count);
    testname= sb.toString();

    SharedPreferences pinfo = getSharedPreferences("pf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= pinfo.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.putString("name", testname);
    editor.putBoolean("safe",false);
    editor.commit();

    patientFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + testname);
    boolean success= true;

    if(patientFolder.exists()){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Already Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        createPatientFolder();
    }

    if(!patientFolder.exists()) {
        success = patientFolder.mkdirs();
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

    if (success) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    } 
    else {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly suggest using a `RecyclerView` + `GridLayoutManager(3)` so you can maintain your code much easier than creating static views. Aleady you can see you have duplicate code. You should create a single `getPatientFour(final String path)` so you can reuse it.

Comment: Jared, thank you so much for responding, I am about to attempt your solution...Yes, I absolutely dont want to use static views! how I can add imageviews to the layout without predefining them? and how can i target those imageviews and insert the image of patient to the corresponding imageview?

Comment: A `RecyclerView` is a like a `Listview` . See here: http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use an Imageview array. The only difference in your getPatientXX() methods is the folder number i.e., Patient1, Patient2, etc.

It is easy to have a loop to iterate through the imageviews and set the image path.

```
   public void getPatients() {
for(int i=0;i<patient.length;i++)
{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PerinatalMonitor/Patient"+i+"/patient.jpg";
    File imgFile = new File(path);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        patient[i].setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    }
}
}
```

Where, patient is the imageview array. This method will iterate through the whole imageview array fetching images from the folder.

Comment: Thank you for responding Trinadh...youre method is very easy to implement...but how do i target the imageviews and insert the corresponding images? maybe I shouldnt have pre-defined imageviews, is there a way to insert imageviews as I add the patients?

Comment: As of now you can define imageview array in your initializeViews() method  like "patient[1]=  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.patient_one);" for all the imageViews. If you want to add imageviews as you add patients, you need to have dynamic allocation of imageview array and the method getPatient() should be called after createPatient() call